# Как взаимодействовать с данным из таблицы Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, ms-word, qt-designer, pyside2

Есть таблица, в первый ее столбик пользователь вносит дату в формате
(`час.минуты.день.месяц.год`). 
После чего по нажатию на кнопку во второй столбец должна выводится разница времени от первой строчки до второй, после от второй до третьей и тд. Выглядит это так:

[image: Красным отмечена нужная таблица]

Я сделал вот такой код:
**test_ui.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        if (self.tableWidget.columnCount() < 2):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        if (self.tableWidget.rowCount() < 3):
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(u"tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(130)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f, \u0447\u0430\u0441", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None));
```

Логика такая: **main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from test_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

Window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(Window)
Window.setFixedSize(320, 240)
Window.show()

def buttonLoader():
    rows = ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
    cols = ui.tableWidget.columnCount()
    data = []
    for row in range(rows):
        tmp = []
        for col in range(cols):
            try:
                tmp.append(ui.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
            except:
                tmp.append('')
        data.append(tmp)

    data_for_word = []
    for i in data: print(i)

    for i in data:
        if i[0] != '':
            data_for_word.append(i)

    for item in data:
        if any(item):
            data_for_word.append({
                "data": item[0],
                "time": item[1]
            })

    doc = DocxTemplate('test_ui.docx')

    context = {
        'tbl_contents': data_for_word
    }

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save('table.docx')


ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(buttonLoader)


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Здесь данные получаются из таблицы и вставляются в шаблон `word`. 
Такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, как сделать такие вычисления не знаю. Если кто знает напишите пример или дополните мой код пример.

Comment: `QDateTime` имеет такой метод как `secsTo` из него можно получить часы

Comment: Можете пример привести, а то пока что не очень понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаком с библиотекой **`docxtpl`**,
поэтому я закомментировал все что с ней связано.

Я так понял, что вам нужен многомерный список,
который содержит сведения о дате и какое-то число
(например, разница времени в часах между первой и второй строками).

Если это так, то `data_for_word` получается по нажатию на 'Считать данные'.

Если этого для вас мало, то как-то предоставьте **`test_ui.docx`**
с таблицей, которую вы редактируете и я попробую посмотреть
что у вас еще не так.

```
'''
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *
#from docxtpl import DocxTemplate                   # pip install docxtpl

#from test_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        if (self.tableWidget.columnCount() < 2):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        if (self.tableWidget.rowCount() < 3):
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(u"tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(130)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f, \u0447\u0430\u0441", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None));
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonLoader)
        
        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
            )
            date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
                lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, 0)             
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        
        for row in range(1, self.tableWidget.rowCount()):    
            dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row-1, 0).dateTime()
            dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item) 

    def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):
        if row == 0:
            dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row+1, 0).dateTime()
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 1, item) 
            return
            
        dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row-1, 0).dateTime()
        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item) 
        
        if row != self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1:
            dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row+1, 0).dateTime()
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 1, item)                 
        
    def buttonLoader(self):
        pass
        data_for_word = []
        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            dateTime = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).\
                       dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row, 1)
            _data = item.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            data_for_word.append([dateTime, _data])
        
        print(f'\n{data_for_word}\n')
        print(* data_for_word, sep='\n')                      


'''    
        doc = DocxTemplate('test_ui.docx')
        context = {
            'tbl_contents': data_for_word
        }
        doc.render(context)
        doc.save('table.docx')        
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 10, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**Update**

> Мне не понятна логика вычисления разницы времени.

---

В колонке с индексом **`0`** у нас `QDateTimeEdit`. 
Класс `QDateTimeEdit` предоставляет виджет для редактирования даты и времени.

> void QDateTimeEdit::dateTimeChanged(const QDateTime &datetime)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается всякий раз, когда изменяется дата или время.
> Новые дата и время передаются в `datetime`.

Мы также дополнительно передаеи в слот `date_changed()`
номер строки `row=row`, в которой происходят изменения.

```
    ...
    for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
        date_from.setDateTime(
            QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
        )
        date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
            lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)
    ...
```

В методе `date_changed()` производим вычисления разницы времени,
как только изменяется дата или время в какой-либо строке.

```
...
def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):

    if row == 0:      # если изменения в строке, т.е. в первой строке
        dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row+1, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 1, item) 
        return        # выходим, т.к. все что связано с изменением
                      # dateTime в первой строке сделали
    
    # для других строк 2, 3, ..., т.е. не первой         
    dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row-1, 0).dateTime()
    dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
    item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item) 

    # для других строк 2, 3, ..., кроме последней строки !         
    if row != self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1:
        dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row+1, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row+1, 1, item)
```

---

> dateTime : QDateTime
>
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#dateTime-prop
>
> Это свойство содержит `QDateTime`, установленный в `QDateTimeEdit`.

```
 #  QDateTime <-          QDateTimeEdit.dateTime()    
    dateTime1 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row-1, 0).dateTime()
    dateTime2 = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
    
    item = QTableWidgetItem()
```

> qint64 QDateTime::secsTo(const QDateTime &other) const
>
> Возвращает количество секунд от `dateTime1` до другого `dateTime2`.
> Если другое dateTime2 раньше, чем это dateTime1,
> возвращаемое значение отрицательное.

```
    #                            vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)             
    self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item)
```

Comment: Еще маленький вопрос. Если знаете, то как в qt disgner добавить dataEdit в таблицу?

Comment: @Андрей Александров это уже другой вопрос. Если вы зададите новый вопрос и приложите свой модуль `.ui` - наверняка вам кто-то поможет. А пока мы говорим о текущем вопросе, что не так в моем ответе?

Comment: В вашем ответе все правильно. Просто задал еще один мини вопрос.

Comment: тогда можете чуть детальней объяснить логику работы примера?

Comment: @Андрей Александров пожалуйста, спрашивайте конкретный вещи. Какая строчка вам не понятна. А логика взята из вашего вопроса, как вы написали - так я и сделал.

Comment: извините за расплывчатость. Мне не понятна логика вычисления разницы времени. То есть как происходит расчет(строчки кода и тд).

Comment: @АндрейАлександров я добавил в свой ответ некоторые комментарии, проверьте. Если мои пояснения помогли вам - не забудьте отметить мой ответ и как полезный.

Comment: задал вопрос, вот ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325401/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python

Answer (score 0):

> вносит дату в формате ( час.минуты.день.месяц.время* )

- наверное опечатка и имеется в виду год

В нахождении разницы между двумя датами в часах можно обратиться к классу [QDateTime](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QDateTime.html)

```
# Для PySide2
from PySide2.QtCore import QDateTime
# PySide6
from PySide6.QtCore import QDateTime
# PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime

# Формат представления даты
format = "hh:mm dd.MM.yyyy"

# Пример задания дат в соответствии с форматом
dateTime1 = QDateTime.fromString("12:34 01.01.2021", format)
dateTime2 = QDateTime.fromString("12:54 01.01.2021", format)

# Получение разницы между датами в секундах
# /60. - в минутах
# /60. в часах
print(dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
```

Comment: Если запустить данный код то  в ответе получится 0,(3) что не верно.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров почему вы считаете что это не верно? Сколько по вашему должно быть?  Что такое 0,(3) ?

Comment: Ааа, дошло.  Я по привычку ищу разницу в минутах, а тут час. Извиняюсь был не прав. А как теперь подставить данные вычисления под таблицу- пример?

Comment: @АндрейАлександров Вы сами попробуйте подставить данные, если не получится, то зададите соответствующий вопрос. Там ничего сложного, просто попробуйте самостоятельно